# Compare two SPUser variable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, spuser

I validate two `SPUser` values inside `if` condition.

Both `SPUser` variables have values when my program runs, but when both `SPUser` values are same my app runs and enter inside if condition. Ideally it should not be.

Where I'm going wrong?

```
if (ownerUser != currentUser)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare Reference objects unless they implement IEquatable interface.

Or it should override equal method with custom implementation.

I would suggest you compare `SPUser.LoginName` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. Seems you are correct. I'll try and let you know when I'm good...

Comment: Yes. It works. You are great.. Thanks @Amal Hashim